# Most braces in one season in Premier League

Tags: football

What is the record of most braces in the Premier League season and who holds it?

Braces - two (or more) goals in a match (if I'm correct)

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. A brace is typically defined as two, with a hat trick being three (and beyond this somewhat depending on the sport and the country). Can you clarify that you are looking for player with most matches scoring more than one (two or more), or just exactly two goals?

Comment: @Nij - two or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've managed to find:

42-match season:

Alan Shearer (93/94) - 10 times 2 or more goals

38-match season:

Kevin Phillips (99/00), Thierry Henry (05/06), Cristiano Ronaldo (07/08), Luis Suarez (13/14) - 9 times 2 or more goals